# Debugging "chroot: failed to load command '<executable_name>'" besides ldd and /proc/<pid>/maps

Tags: chroot, debugging

Trying to run `rngd` from `rng-tools` in a `chroot` environment on Raspberry Pi Zero.

Running `ldd` with the same `chroot` shows that all dependencies are satisfied:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ sudo chroot /home/pi/rngd_chroot/ ldd /sbin/rngd
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb6f77000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb6e29000)
        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6fa1000)
```

The actual libraries used by a running non-`chroot` instance of the same `rngd` executable are also under the `chroot` folder:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ ps -aux | grep rngd
root       262  0.0  0.3  27640  1432 ?        SLsl 14:05   0:00 /usr/sbin/rngd -r /dev/hwrng
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ sudo cat /proc/262/maps
00008000-00010000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 20512      /usr/sbin/rngd
00010000-00011000 rw-p 00008000 b3:02 20512      /usr/sbin/rngd
0197c000-0197d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
0197d000-01981000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
01981000-0199d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
b5400000-b5421000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b5421000-b5500000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b55c0000-b55c1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b55c1000-b5dc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b5dc1000-b5dc2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b5dc2000-b65c2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b65c2000-b65c3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
b65c3000-b6dc3000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6dc3000-b6efb000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 5239       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
b6efb000-b6f0b000 ---p 00138000 b3:02 5239       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
b6f0b000-b6f0d000 r--p 00138000 b3:02 5239       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
b6f0d000-b6f0e000 rw-p 0013a000 b3:02 5239       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc-2.28.so
b6f0e000-b6f11000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6f11000-b6f28000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 5412       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
b6f28000-b6f37000 ---p 00017000 b3:02 5412       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
b6f37000-b6f38000 r--p 00016000 b3:02 5412       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
b6f38000-b6f39000 rw-p 00017000 b3:02 5412       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread-2.28.so
b6f39000-b6f3b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6f3b000-b6f3d000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 5217       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so
b6f3d000-b6f4c000 ---p 00002000 b3:02 5217       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so
b6f4c000-b6f4d000 r--p 00001000 b3:02 5217       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so
b6f4d000-b6f4e000 rw-p 00002000 b3:02 5217       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libarmmem-v6l.so
b6f4e000-b6f6e000 r-xp 00000000 b3:02 5130       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
b6f7b000-b6f7d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
b6f7e000-b6f7f000 r--p 00020000 b3:02 5130       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
b6f7f000-b6f80000 rw-p 00021000 b3:02 5130       /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-2.28.so
bebb6000-bebd7000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [stack]
becab000-becac000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [sigpage]
ffff0000-ffff1000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vectors]
```

---

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ sudo find . | grep -v -e "/dev/" -e "/sys/" -e "/proc/"
.
./sbin
./sbin/rngd
./usr
./usr/share
./usr/share/lintian
./usr/share/lintian/overrides
./usr/share/lintian/overrides/rng-tools
./bin
./bin/rngtest
./bin/sh
./bin/bash
./bin/ldd
./lib
./lib/libarmmem-v6l.so
./lib/libpthread.so.0
./lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
./lib/ld-2.28.so
./lib/libtinfo.so.6
./lib/libc.so.6
./lib/libc-2.28.so
./lib/libtinfo.so.6.1
./lib/libpthread-2.28.so
./lib/libdl.so.2
./lib/libdl-2.28.so
./sys
./dev
./var
./var/run
./proc
```

But when attempting to run `rngd` with `chroot` I'm receiving this:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ sudo chroot /home/pi/rngd_chroot/ /sbin/rngd
chroot: failed to run command ‘/sbin/rngd’: No such file or directory
```

Just to demonstrate that I have a valid `rngd` executable there running it without `chroot`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ sudo sbin/rngd
can't lock /var/run/rngd.pid, running daemon's pid may be 262
```

Any suggestions how to debug this are appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR;
`rngd` requires */lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux.so.3* (*program interpreter*) to exist in this exact location when you run the executable, unlike `ldd` it doesn't resolve it to */lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3*

---

This [great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982078/578) about the program interpreter mechanism pointed me in the right direction.

To figure this out I first found and tried using the [LD_DEBUG](http://www.bnikolic.co.uk/blog/linux-ld-debug.html) environment variable:

```
sudo chroot /home/pi/rngd_chroot/ bash
bash-5.0# LD_DEBUG=libs rngd
bash: /sbin/rngd: No such file or directory
```

Setting `LD_DEBUG` results in no output for `rng` but there IS output for `bash` so I figured it didn't even load the *program interpreter* library (*ld-linux*).

Assuming that the library search is done by *ld-linux* it makes sense that it cannot find *ld-linux* itself if it's not at the exact location (*/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux.so.3* in my case).

Not sure why `ldd` is not reporting this as a missing library. I guess it's a <s>bug</s> feature of `ldd`.

Also if we compare the `ldd` output for `bash` and `rng`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ ldd bin/bash
        ...
        /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f9b000)    
pi@raspberrypi:~/rngd_chroot $ ldd sbin/rngd
        ...
        /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ld-linux.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 (0xb6f10000)
```

For `bash` it doesn't have the left-hand side part, it just shows the actual local path of the *program interpreter*.

I guess this has to do with how one links executables.

If anyone has more insight into what exactly happens and what is the proper terminology for these 2 types of *program interpreter* linking please post it as an answer or a comment (I'll add it here).

Comment: There's also this cool [linking issues troubleshooting site](http://linkdemo.carabinerweb.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/) which didn't help, but might be useful to others.